# Is it possible to force a user to install an apk while connecting to my WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi, mobile

While user connects to my wifi network, I want to install the app on the user phone to encrypt the request. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why would any sane mobile os allow this? What request are you trying to encrypt?

Comment: In an enterprise BYOD environment this can be enforced, It's common that when you connect to a Wi-Fi they run a basic scan to know if you comply the security needs, and ***TRY TO PUSH*** an APK of a verified anti-virus or pretty much anything they need you to comply with. But I'm not sure what you mean by encrypt the request, which request? It's somewhat achievable but your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach to your case is to use `Captive Portal`

It's a login page that requires username and password to access the internet, you most likely have encountered this when using public wifi networks in airports or coffee shops.

I haven't tried it, but try replacing the username and password fields with a download button and use some social engineering techniques like saying 'Download app to have better internet speed!'

Here's a [link](https://www.linksys.com/us/r/resource-center/captive-portal/) to learn more about captive portal setup.